# Flutter submit data to http.post timeout issue

Tags: php, flutter, post

I have a flutter app where data is submitted via http.post to a php/mysql server.  The data is then inserted into the database.  Usually everything works fine and I have a timeout built in where if the time is exceeded it returns a "could not connect" error back to the flutter client.

Occasionally though, the app times out but the data is still submitted and inserted.  I'm thinking that the data posted to the server but for whatever reason a response was not received back in time.

Looking for help or ideas on how maybe to make my code better to deal with this issue other then just increasing the timeout.  Thanks.

```
postData() async {
    const url = 'https://www.testdomain.com/app/submit.php';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
        "id": user,
        "notes": notesController.text
      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 4), onTimeout: () {
        //Time has run out
        return http.Response('Error', 408);
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 408) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          status = '1';
        });
      } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final auth = json.decode(response.body);
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          success = auth[0]['success'].toString();
          status = auth[0]['status'].toString();
        });
      } else {
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          status = '1';
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        status = '1';
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: why you set the timeout 4 seconds? by default timeout for api request is 60s. and its depends on the connection and data load.  its hard to promise your api request done before 4s if your connection is very slow or the data is too big. also you need to optimize the process in the backend to be done before the timeout.

Comment: check for common error codes as well, like these https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-http-error-codes
You may also need to extend the success code check to accept the range of succesful status codes, like ```bool isSuccessful(int statusCode) {return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;}``` 
then check ```isSuccessful(response.statusCode){final auth=json.decode(response.body);
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {success = auth[0]['success'].toString();status = auth[0]['status'].toString();});}```

Answer (score 1):

Increase Timeout Judiciously:
If the occasional timeout issue is due to the server sometimes taking longer to respond, you might consider increasing the timeout duration slightly.

```dart
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
   "id": user,
   "notes": notesController.text
}).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
   // Handle timeout appropriately
});
```

Check Timeout on the Server Side:

```
 <?php
// Set the maximum execution time 
set_time_limit(150);

//Other Your Code
// ...
?>
```

**Important: Check Response Confirmation:**

In your PHP code, after successfully inserting data into the database:

```php
echo json_encode(["success" => true, "message" => "Data successfully inserted"]);
```

And in your Dart code:

```dart
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   final auth = json.decode(response.body);
   if (auth["success"]) {
      // Data was successfully inserted
   
   } else {
      // Check Other Http Statuses
   }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of that extra test inside of the 200 status code, I will try that.  Also will increase the timeouts to 10.  Thanks